# Deleting folder named trash 1001 on Transcend external drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have been trying to delete this folder named.Trash 1001 on my external drive.Whenever I plug in my external to windows 7 machine,I log in as administrator,and open the drive and I try to delete it,a pop up box appears indicating that I have no administrative rights and I should have permission to perform the delete action.
[This is the folder,before performing delete action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRNxN.png)

[This is the popup box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHicH.png)

Comment: You should take ownership of the folder and its contents before you attempt to delete it.  You being an administrator does not matter, Windows respects NTFS permissions of another Windows installation, basically your user nor machines Administrator user group is contained in the folder's ACL.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for your feedback.I have tried to take ownership of the folder under it's properties.But still the folder can't be deleted or removed.

Comment: Run `icacls .Trash-1001` from Command Prompt, and post back what it shows. Make sure you include the folder's full path.